# How does UnblockSit.es work?

Tags: vpn, proxy

UnblockSit.es is a proxy site, however it is a little different to onces I've seen before.

Rather than using a PHP or other server side script to fetch and display a page, it seems to do everything through server configuration. The site URL has some funky DNS settings going on, so that you can enter any domain before it, for example, `http://serverfault.com.prx2.unblocksit.es/`, and it displays it.

This seems to work for any site, so it's not a manual configuration.

Are there any packages which could offer this, or is it entirely custom?

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty trivial to setup:

- Multiple wildcard A records (*.unblocksit.es, *.*.unblocksit.es, *.*.*.unblocksit.es, etc) - so any request goes back to their webserver.
- Apache config or PHP script that reads the requested URL, strips off the end, and proxies the content.

Answer (score 1):

What that's likely doing is checking the `Host` header that your web browser is sending to determine what domain to proxy to (and using wildcard DNS to make all the subdomains under their domain go to their server).

That part's easy, but translating any resource requests to also use the proxied domain is a much trickier problem to solve.  Something like Apache's `mod_proxy_html` attempts to solve this problem, but relies on a pretty crude strategy of text replacement in HTML.

They might be using something like that, or have simply written some custom code to act as the proxy.